# How can I check if the every department's months is existing while comparing it to the`monthsName` array using `startMonth` and endMonth`

Tags: javascript, json, sorting

How can I check if the every department's months is existing while comparing it to the`monthsName` array using `startMonth` and endMonth`

*I'm sorry I can't explain the words properly, This is my alternative to my previous question [How can I return it as a 0 instead of skipping the month in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78018223/how-can-i-return-it-as-a-0-instead-of-skipping-the-month-in-sql)*

This is the code I run after getting the result to the database, it simply group the deparment's `event_count` by `department` and by `month`.

```
function groupDataByDepartment(results, startMonth, endMonth) {
        
        const monthNames = [
          { abbreviation: "Jan", number: 1 },
          { abbreviation: "Feb", number: 2 },
          { abbreviation: "Mar", number: 3 },
          { abbreviation: "Apr", number: 4 },
          { abbreviation: "May", number: 5 },
          { abbreviation: "Jun", number: 6 },
          { abbreviation: "Jul", number: 7 },
          { abbreviation: "Aug", number: 8 },
          { abbreviation: "Sep", number: 9 },
          { abbreviation: "Oct", number: 10 },
          { abbreviation: "Nov", number: 11 },
          { abbreviation: "Dec", number: 12 },
        ];
        
        const groupedData = {};
        let currentID = 1; // Initialize ID counter
        let currentDepartment;
    
        results.forEach((entry) => {
            const { department, year, month, event_count } = entry;
    
            if (department !== currentDepartment) {
                currentDepartment = department;
                currentID = 1; // Reset ID counter when department changes
            }
    
            if (!groupedData[department]) {
                groupedData[department] = [];
                
            }
    
            groupedData[department].push({
                id: currentID++,
                [month]: event_count,
                year: year,
            });
        });
    
        return groupedData;
    }


const groupedData = groupDataByDepartment(sampleResult, 12, 1)
```

Now the result will be like this

```
sampleResult = [
    {
        "department": "Department 1",
        "year": 2022,
        "month": "Dec",
        "event_count": 36
    },
    {
        "department": "Department 1",
        "year": 2023,
        "month": "Jan",
        "event_count": 28
    },
    {
        "department": "Department 2",
        "year": 2022,
        "month": "Dec",
        "event_count": 8
    },
    {
        "department": "Department 2",
        "year": 2023,
        "month": "Jan",
        "event_count": 50
    },
    {
        "department": "Department 3",
        "year": 2022,
        "month": "Dec",
        "event_count": 1
    },
    {
        "department": "Department 3",
        "year": 2023,
        "month": "Jan",
        "event_count": 34
    },
    {
        "department": "Department 4",
        "year": 2023,
        "month": "Jan",
        "event_count": 11
    },
    {
        "department": "Department 5",
        "year": 2022,
        "month": "Dec",
        "event_count": 2
    },
    {
        "department": "Department 5",
        "year": 2023,
        "month": "Jan",
        "event_count": 21
    },
    {
        "department": "Department 6",
        "year": 2022,
        "month": "Dec",
        "event_count": 17
    },
    {
        "department": "Department 6",
        "year": 2023,
        "month": "Jan",
        "event_count": 72
    },
    {
        "department": "Deparment 7",
        "year": 2022,
        "month": "Dec",
        "event_count": 38
    },
    {
        "department": "Deparment 7",
        "year": 2023,
        "month": "Jan",
        "event_count": 14
    },
    {
        "department": "Department 8",
        "year": 2022,
        "month": "Dec",
        "event_count": 44
    },
    {
        "department": "Department 8",
        "year": 2023,
        "month": "Jan",
        "event_count": 132
    }
]
```

What i'm trying to achieve is with the use of `startMonth` and `endMonth`. I want to loop and compare the `monthsName`  and the `sampleResult` and if the month is not existing, still input the month its misssing but make the result as `0`

- `startMonth` = `12`
- `endMonth` = `1`

So in the `sampleResult` in the `Department 4`. The function skip the month of `Dec`, because I don't have any data during `Dec`, instead of leaving it blank, I want it to be like this.

```
sampleResult = [
      ...other results
    {
        "department": "Department 4",
        "year": 2022,
        "month": "Dec",
        "event_count": 0
    },
     {
        "department": "Department 4",
        "year": 2023,
        "month": "Jan",
        "event_count": 11
    },

]
```